# pgAdmin to display multiple result sets

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

With MS SQL Query Browser I can run multiple queries at the same time and each result set will display in it's own window.

Does PostgreSQL/pgAdmin have this functionality? Plugin perhaps?

Comment: One workaround, though obviously not ideal, is through the use of `UNION ALL` as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/623978/how-display-result-of-multi-select-in-pgadmin-iii

Comment: FWIW, DbVisualizer supports multiple results, including in the free edition.  This is certainly a glaring omission from the "official" IDE; one wonders if Postgres developers practice dogfooding.

Answer (score 10):

If started from the same SQL window, then no - you will always get the latest result set (or nothing, if the last command returns no rows, like in the case of `COMMIT`).  Not sure if this is OK for you, but you can open as many query windows as you want and so have as many result sets.

(The above means that I'm not aware any such plugins.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in PGAdmin called "Execute PgScript" (yellow highlighted). You can opt this option to execute multiple statement at once.
[image]